# Dynamically retrieving elements with loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyname

I am new to javascript and I want to get the elements by the name with help of loop but can not get the elements. Kindly help so that i can reduce the lot of code by using loop.

Below are the lines of code

```
function (e){
    for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
        var name = "qption0"+i;
        var clicableObject = document.getElementById(name);
        clicableObject.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
    }
}
```

Above code is in JAVASCRIPT

Comment: You mention get element by name, yet you're using getElementById... If the IDs of your controls aren't qption01-04 then this approach won't work.

Comment: You say you want to get the elements by the name, but you're using `getElementById`

Comment: Are you trying to get it by name or by id?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:-

```
var name = "qption0"+i;
var clicableObject = document.getElementsByName(name);
clicableObject.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00"
```

Thats it..
Hope it helps...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @kmb385 Ya...actually I am a newbiee at stackoverflow :p..But now i have turned it into an answer..:)

Comment: excellent work.  I encourage you to keep visiting the community, its pretty easy to get the hang of the site.

Answer (score 0):

When changing an elements background color via Javascript the syntax of the statement is `elem.style.backgroundColor`.  The provided code omits the `.style.` portion of this call.

```
function (e){
    for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
        var name  = "qption0"+i;
        var clicableObject  = document.getElementById(name);        
        clicableObject.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00"; //notice .style.back..
}
```

For further information check out [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `style` object..

```
clicableObject.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
```